# EOF error despite using FreeFile

Tags: excel, vba, eof

I have the following problem in VBA

```
Dim backupFile As Integer
Dim backupFName As String

backupFName = xBackupDirName & "\" & "swap_backup_cf_" & xSwapID & ".txt"
backupFile = fopenForReading(backupFName)

Dim tmp  As String
tmp = getLine(backupFile)

Dim b As Boolean
b = EOF(backupFile)
```

The `fopenforReading` and `getLine` is just what you would expect (I just come from a C++ background and these names come to mind faster). The problem is that the last line gives me "Bad file name or number" error. However, the `tmp=getLine(backupFile)` reads the `backupFile` successfully. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Just for completeness:

```
Public Function fopenForReading(xFname As String) As Integer
    Dim iFile As Integer
    iFile = FreeFile            
    Open xFname For Input As #iFile
    fopenForReading = iFile
End Function

Public Function getLine(iFile As Integer) As String
   Dim line As String
   Line Input #iFile, line
   getLine = line
End Function
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me (Excel 2010), with the only modification being the file name. My best guess is that (assuming that to be an extract, which is probably a safe assumption) somewhere along the way the value of backupFile is being either changed or lost OR the file is already closed somehow.

I'd suggest putting two breakpoints in the code, one at the Freefile command to check the number being returned (odds are that it'll be "1", but check anyway) and one at the EOF command so that you can check the value of backupFile just before it executes.

The other thing that occurs to me is that the getLine function call is probably somewhere inside a loop; make sure that fopenforReading isn't called again inside the loop as well. Just a possibility.

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you. Unfortunately, it's not an extract. I am running on 2003 and even just running the incriminated lines in a separate Sub gives me the same error. The file number does not get changed during calculations.

Comment: I checked with a colleague of mine and the sample code works for him as well. So I have no idea what might be wrong.

Comment: Huge long shot, but check your list of references (Tools -> References) to see whether there are any invalid ones. I've occasionally seen invalid references screw up seemingly completely unrelated VBA code. Also try compiling the project (Debug menu) to see whether it throws an error. Last thing is to go to Windows Update and ensure that you've installed all updates on Excel though admittedly one security update in late August played merry havoc with some of my VBA projects until a couple of .ocx controls were re-registered. Doesn't sound like the same problem on yours though; better to update

Comment: Alan, compilation returns no problems and my references are OK too. Updates are most likely taken care of by the IT dpt. And if they were not taken care ok, I can't do much about it:) However, I have figured out that when I open the file for output normally by `Open .. for output as #...`, all goes fine... still no idea why. Many thanks!

Comment: One last thing, I have all these file related function in a separate xla file. I dont know whether it changes anything..